# Hindi speech recognition for iOS

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

Is there any API/SDK that supports speech recognition of Hindi language?
It can be a web API or an SDK for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has provided the speech APIs for English language
using System.Speech.Recognition;
but there is no speech APIs specially for Hindi Recognition.